# Passive integrator circuit in PSpice

Tags: voltage

I'm trying to draw a plot of a passive integrator circuit. I think it's not correct as it should look like this:

[image]

but mine looks like this (it's Vout/Vin on the right):
[image: Passive integrator circuit]

I also don't know what voltage source should I choose (Vac/Vsin/Vpulse?) - I used pulse (as I saw it in a tutorial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph on the right showing your voltages is fine but are you aware the graph is Vout divided by Vin. Try displaying just Vout - this should show you exactly what you want to see.